# archaic -an conjugation

Tags: archaic-language

This is a prayer uttered by someone who I presume is imitating archaic speech:

> 遍く邪悪より御身を守らん

What is the conjugation used in 守らん? It's doesn't seem like a negative which was my first thought.

Answer (score 12):

守らむ(守らん) consists of the imperfective form (未然形) of 守る + the auxiliary verb む(ん); meaning #2 in [助動詞 む](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/214421/m0u/%E3%82%80/).  I think it's the archaic form of 守ろう.