# The meaning of てくれん in 「アギマの領地を削り取ってくれん」

Tags: grammar, meaning

I came across this line recently and don't know how to interpret it. For context, the speaker is the commander of a foreign army and his forces have just met those of the アギマ王国 on the battlefield. He says this line to the アギマ army's commander before the battle.

> ついに追い詰めたぞ！この度こそワシが勝利し、アギマの領地を削り取ってくれん！

I initially assumed くれん was the shortened form of 呉れない but that doesn't make much sense, does it? Could someone explain what くれん is doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a combination of the followings:

1. "Arrogant and derogatory くれる", used when the speaker does something bad to others or when someone does something bad to the speaker

   - [Why is くれる used here and not あげる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40560/5010) (see the third example)
   - [Using くれる for doing something bad](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/938/5010)
2. Archaic volitional auxiliary む, which is also written as ん

   - [archaic -an conjugation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14414/5010)
   - [What is the verb ending of われん mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33867/5010)

So 削り取ってくれん is an even more pompous/arrogant/old-fashioned version of 削り取ってくれよう or 削り取ってやろう (This やる is used in the second sense [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14416/5010).)